# How to prefill geopoint in enketo form through URL

Tags: xforms, odk, odk-xform, xlsform

I want to pre fill geopoint(latitude,longitude,altitude,accuracy) through URL?

i tried like this : `www.myform.com?d[/data/myformname/lat]=28.5825583292`
but it not reflected in form. Can anybody help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the value is the issue, if you are trying to populate a geopoint value directly. See the space-separated format (like "10 10 10 10") that Collect or Enketo submits to your server for a geopoint field. Also make sure to URL encode the query string when you are testing manually-crafted URLs.

I presume you are doing this just for testing and will use Enketo's API for actual deployment which is the recommended way, because we don't attempt to keep URL formats stable (only API endpoints).